# Converting a Buffer into a ReadableStream in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer

I have a library that takes as input a `ReadableStream`, but my input is just a base64 format image. I could convert the data I have in a `Buffer` like so:

```
var img = new Buffer(img_string, 'base64');
```

But I have no idea how to convert it to a `ReadableStream` or convert the `Buffer` I obtained to a `ReadableStream`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can create a ReadableStream using [Node Stream Buffers](https://github.com/samcday/node-stream-buffer) like so:

```
// Initialize stream
var myReadableStreamBuffer = new streamBuffers.ReadableStreamBuffer({
  frequency: 10,      // in milliseconds.
  chunkSize: 2048     // in bytes.
}); 

// With a buffer
myReadableStreamBuffer.put(aBuffer);

// Or with a string
myReadableStreamBuffer.put("A String", "utf8");
```

The frequency cannot be 0 so this will introduce a certain delay.

Comment: Thanks, even though a bit late. I don't remember how I solved the problem, but this looks a nice solution. If anybody confirm this it would be great. I remember finding ZERO about this conversion.

Comment: Confirming that it works - found this when looking up how to turn filebuffers into streams.

Comment: If you have files you deal with files you should rather open a file read stream straight away with this:
http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Comment: Milliseconds is not a measurement of frequency - I suppose they mean period.

Comment: @UpTheCreek I cannot change it as this is the property name and the unit IS milliseconds.

Comment: @vanthome - I wasn't suggesting it was your fault :) Just poor naming on the part of the node-stream-buffer devs.

Comment: _"Node Stream Buffer is obviously designed for use in testing; the inability to avoid a delay makes it a poor choice for production use."_ — [Bryan Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18190310/65732)

Answer (score 241):

For nodejs 10.17.0 and up:

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const stream = Readable.from(myBuffer);
```

Comment: does this have any impact on image files?

Comment: It will work for the case described by OP, but in case the buffer contains binary data `.toString()` will corrupt it

Answer (score 100):

something like this...

```
import { Readable } from 'stream'

const buffer = new Buffer(img_string, 'base64')
const readable = new Readable()
readable._read = () => {} // _read is required but you can noop it
readable.push(buffer)
readable.push(null)

readable.pipe(consumer) // consume the stream
```

In the general course, a readable stream's `_read` function should collect data from the underlying source and `push` it incrementally ensuring you don't harvest a huge source into memory before it's needed.

In this case though you already have the source in memory, so `_read` is not required.

Pushing the whole buffer just wraps it in the readable stream api.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to `push()` the buffer inside the `_read()` method?  I.e. `readable._read = () => {readable.push(buffer); readable.push(null);}` . Not sure it matters, but allowing the stream to manage the timing of when data is fed into seems less likely to run into unexpected behavior.

Other than that this should be the accepted answer, as it doesn't rely on 3rd party modules.

Comment: Generally, you'd be right, but for this specific use case I wouldn't `push` inside the `read` method. Conceptually I think `_read` should be reserved for "harvesting" data from an underlying source. In this case we not only have the data in memory, but no conversion is required. So for wrapping data in a stream this is how I would do it, but for converting or accumulating data in a stream, that logic would happen in the `_read` method.

Comment: Your underlying source is the buffer ;)

Comment: @FranckFreiburger Yes, but you're not "harvesting" data from that source, it's already in memory and you're always going to consume it all in one go, you're not pulling it in on demand.

Answer (score 36):

[Node Stream Buffer](https://github.com/samcday/node-stream-buffer) is obviously designed for use in testing; the inability to avoid a delay makes it a poor choice for production use.

[Gabriel Llamas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458093/gabriel-llamas) suggests [streamifier](https://github.com/gagle/Node-Streamifier) in this answer:   [How to wrap a buffer as a stream2 Readable stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038705/how-a-wrap-a-buffer-as-a-stream2-readable-stream#16039177)

Answer (score 24):

You can use the standard NodeJS stream API for this - [stream.Readable.from](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromiterable-options)

```js
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const stream = Readable.from(buffer);
```

> Note: Don't convert a buffer to string (`buffer.toString()`) if the buffer contains binary data. It will lead to corrupted binary files.

Comment: I noted that this only works with Node.js 12+. The "readable.push(buffer)" method works with Node.js 8.17.0 and Node.js 10.24.1 in my tests. As I stick to supported Node.js versions, it is a non-issue for me.

Comment: It's clean and also it works for me.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to add a whole npm lib for a single file. i refactored it to typescript:

```
import { Readable, ReadableOptions } from "stream";

export class MultiStream extends Readable {
  _object: any;
  constructor(object: any, options: ReadableOptions) {
    super(object instanceof Buffer || typeof object === "string" ? options : { objectMode: true });
    this._object = object;
  }
  _read = () => {
    this.push(this._object);
    this._object = null;
  };
}
```

based on [node-streamifier](https://github.com/gagle/node-streamifier/blob/master/lib/index.js) (the best option as said above).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple solution using *[streamifier](https://github.com/gagle/node-streamifier)* module.

```
const streamifier = require('streamifier');
streamifier.createReadStream(new Buffer ([97, 98, 99])).pipe(process.stdout);
```

You can use Strings, Buffer and Object as its arguments.

Comment: Another equivalent alternative is [tostream](https://github.com/seedalpha/tostream):
`const toStream = require('tostream'); toStream(new Buffer ([97, 98, 99])).pipe(process.stdout);`

Comment: @YushinWashio Definitely. Plenty of modules are available in Node.

Answer (score 7):

This is my simple code for this.

```
import { Readable } from 'stream';

const newStream = new Readable({
                    read() {
                      this.push(someBuffer);
                    },
                  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const Duplex = require('stream').Duplex;  // core NodeJS API
function bufferToStream(buffer) {  
  let stream = new Duplex();
  stream.push(buffer);
  stream.push(null);
  return stream;
}
```

Source: 
Brian Mancini -> http://derpturkey.com/buffer-to-stream-in-node/