# Read strings line by line from Buffer instance in Node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js module which exports two functions `init(data)` , where `data` is `Buffer` ,and `test(word)` , where `word` is a string.

I would like to read lines from `data` `Buffer` instance line by line inside `test()` function .

I have no experience in Node.js, only JS. All I come to know from this stack is how to export multiple function from Node.js module.

Here is function declaration so far:

```
module.exports = {
    init: function(data) {

    },
    test: function(word) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

according to your comment, `data` is `instanceof Buffer`, and it contains a dictionary with one english word per line. So, now you can convert `data` to array of string, splitting by *new line* characters. with `module` format:

```
module.exports.init = function (data) {
    if (!(data instanceof Buffer)) {
        throw new Error('not a instanceof Buffer');
    }
    this.currentData = data.toString().split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g);
};

module.exports.test = function (word) {
    // for example
    var yourTestMethod = function (lineNumber, lineContent, testWord) {
        return true;
    };
    if (this.currentData && this.currentData.length) {
        for (var line = 0; line < this.currentData.length; line++) {
            if (yourTestMethod(line, this.currentData[line], word)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

if you save this code as *testModule.js*, you can use this module in main code like:

```
// load module
var testModule = require('./testModule.js');

// init
var buf = new Buffer(/* load dictionaly */);
testModule.init(buf);

// test
console.log(testModule.test('foo'));
```

I think it is more simple. thanks.

---

(old answer)

I think you can use `readline` module.
But readline accepts a `stream`, not a `buffer`.
So it needs to convert. for example.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');

// string to buffer
var baseText = 'this is a sample text\n(empty lines ...)\n\n\n\nend line:)';
var buf = new Buffer(baseText);

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038705/how-to-wrap-a-buffer-as-a-stream2-readable-stream
var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.end(buf);

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: bufferStream,
});

var count = 0;
rl.on('line', function (line) {
    console.log('this is ' + (++count) + ' line, content = ' + line);
});
```

then output is:

```
> node test.js
this is 1 line, content = this is a sample text
this is 2 line, content = (empty lines ...)
this is 3 line, content =
this is 4 line, content =
this is 5 line, content =
this is 6 line, content = end line:)
```

how is that?

Comment: Please check my question and answer how can i use data variable inside  test function so that i can do something like this var buffer =  new Buffer(data) and use yours answer . Plus correct me if i assumed anything wrong regarding argument usage

Comment: what do you mean by _data Buffer_? `(data instanceof Buffer) === true`?

Comment: oh, my answer is too complex for your problem. The content of `data` is string, right?

Comment: yes , its actually a dictionary with one english word per line