# Store file to MinIO from browser form (Angular2)

Tags: angular, file-upload, base64, minio

I'm doing a prototype of an Angular8 app that can upload files from a form to MinIO.
Here is the form :

upload-form.component.html :

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" required />
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" class="flex__item--middle u-1/3 u-mt+" type="sumbit">
    Upload
</button>
```

Here is the ts :

upload-form.component.ts

```js
onFileChanged(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;

      this.uploadForm.patchValue({
        fileName: file.name,
        fileSize: file.size
      });

      
    
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.uploadForm.patchValue({
          fileStream: reader.result
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      };
    }
  }
  
  // ... here is the service call 
  // this.uploadService.sendMinIO(form_values).then(...
```

and here is the API call to MinIO putObject function :

`minioClient.putObject(bucketName, fileName, fileStream, fileSize, function (err, etag)`.

The Angular service is not relevant since it just pass the data unchanged.

With this method, the file is created and stored but the content is the base64 encoded string I got from the FileReader. I tried several method in order to get the file content.

[MinIO wait for a "stream" (Readable Stream)](https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference#putObject) so i tried to use Buffer (new Buffer(string, "base64")...., or [streamifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038705/how-to-wrap-a-buffer-as-a-stream2-readable-stream#16039177) and other tricks but I think there is something basic I don't understand here.

What do I have to do to store the data coming from Angular into the initial file in MinIO ?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the headers added in the base64 encoded string by [`readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) (check the note in the API docs) in the server. For example:

```
const { file } = req.body; // the base64 encoded string
const buffer = Buffer.from(file.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
```

if the file is an image (png, jpeg) or:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(file.replace(/^data:application\/pdf;base64,/, ""),'base64');
```

if the file is a pdf document and then add it in the bucket:

```
minioClient.putObject('bucket', 'filename', buffer)
```