# How to pass a Buffer as argument of fs.createReadStream

Tags: node.js

According to docs 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

fs.createReadStream() can accept Buffer as first argument

my node code:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var faker = require('faker')
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx')

var gg = _.range(10).map((item) => {
  return _.range(10).map((item) => {
    return faker.name.findName()
  })
})

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var buf = xlsx.build([{
    name: 'sheet1',
    data: gg
  }])
  fs.createReadStream(buf, 'binary').pipe(res)

}).listen(9090)
```

but I get this error:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Path must be a string without null bytes
at nullCheck (fs.js:135:14)
at Object.fs.open (fs.js:627:8)
at ReadStream.open (fs.js:1951:6)
at new ReadStream (fs.js:1938:10)
at Object.fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1885:10)
at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/xpg/project/test/index.js:18:6)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
```

[image]

I just want to know that if I want to pass a Buffer as the path argument, what is the options I should provide, passing 'binary' doesn't work.

I try it with both Node 6.11.0 and Node 8.4.0

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230487/converting-a-buffer-into-a-readablestream-in-nodejs

Comment: A file path has to end up being a string that the OS will accept and can't be random binary so it's unclear what you're trying to do by passing a buffer anyway.  If you pass a buffer, it will presumably call `.toString()` on it.

Comment: @ivo -That post has nothing to do with the first argument to `fs.createReadStream()`.

Comment: If a `Buffer` is passed as argument to `fs.createReadStream()`, it should indicate the file path, not file content.

Comment: @shaochuancs can you show me the code?

Comment: @Littlee Sure, please check my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 Due to the fact that he's not passing a path and has a buffer of binary data, I believe that he actually wants to create a readable stream from the buffer contents. I see you suggested that in your accepted answer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The first argument to `fs.createReadStream()` must be the file path.  You can apparently pass the path in a Buffer object, but it still must be an acceptable OS path when the Buffer is converted to a string.

It appears you are trying to pass the file content to `fs.createReadStream()`.  That is not how that API works.  If you look into the code for `fs.createReadStream()` it is completely clear in the code that it is going to call `fs.open()` and pass the first argument from `fs.createReadStream()` as the file path for `fs.open()`.

If what you're trying to do is to create a readable stream from a buffer (no file involved), then you need to do that a different way.  You can see how to do that here in this answer: [Converting a Buffer into a ReadableStream in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44091532/816620).

Conceptually, you just create a readable stream object, push the data you already have into it from your Buffer, push a `null` to signify the end of the stream and create a noop `_read()` method and you're done.  You can then use that readable stream with any other code that expects to read it.

Answer (score 18):

**Creating a Readable Stream From Buffer.**

You can easily create a Readable Stream from a Buffer, however using fs.createReadStream() does indeed require first writing it to a file path.

**Using stream.Duplex()**

- No need to write a local file in order to get a readable stream
- Saves I/O and speeds things up.
- Works everywhere fs.createReadStream() is desired.
- Great for writing to cloud services where local storage my not be feasible.

**Example:**

```
const {Duplex} = require('stream'); // Native Node Module 

function bufferToStream(myBuffer) {
    let tmp = new Duplex();
    tmp.push(myBuffer);
    tmp.push(null);
    return tmp;
}

const myReadableStream = bufferToStream(your_buffer);

// use myReadableStream anywhere you would use a stream 
// created using fs.createReadStream('some_path.ext');
// For really large streams, you may want to pipe the buffer into the Duplex.
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, may be it could be helpful for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039150/nodejs-extract-tar-gizp-archive-and-avoid-err-out-of-range?noredirect=1#comment123811531_70039150

Answer (score 4):

@jfriend00 has already provided a very clear explanation on this issue. If a Buffer object is passed as argument to fs.createReadStream(), it should indicate the file path, not file content. As @Littlee asked in comment, here is an example code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs')

router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var buf = Buffer.from('./test.html');
  fs.createReadStream(buf).pipe(res);
});
```

Please note the Buffer `buf` indicates a file path (`"./test.html"`), not the file `test.html`'s content.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NestJs as Backend, this can be a solution, Good Luck

```
import { StreamableFile } from '@nestjs/common';

# File is type  (file: Express.Multer.File)

const {originalname, buffer} = file;
const streamableObject =  new StreamableFile(buffer),
const readStream  = streamableObject.stream
```

Documentation about Streamable Class, in my particular case I used this code to upload files to Google Drive Api, given that Api Google requires a createReadStream()
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files