# Nodejs extract tar gizp archive and avoid ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, tar

I'm trying to extract a big tar archive using [zlib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlib) and [tar-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar-stream) libraries. The problem is that I'm getting a `ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE` exception due to the file size:

```
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "length" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 2147483647. Received 3179560960
```

My code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const tar = require('tar-stream');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

const extract = tar.extract();
const gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

var chunks = [];
extract.on('entry', function (header, stream, next) {
    stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    stream.on('end', function () {
        next();
    });
    stream.resume();
});
extract.on('finish', async function () {
    if (chunks.length) {
        var data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        await writeFile(destPath, data);
        logger.info("wrote %s", destPath);
    }
})
    .on('error', (error) => {
        logger.warn("gunzip error:%@", error.toString());
    })

fs.createReadStream(tmpPath)
    .pipe(gunzip)
    .pipe(extract)
```

Stack trace:

```
internal/validators.js:97
      throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE(name, `>= ${min} && <= ${max}`, value);
      ^

RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "length" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 2147483647. Received 3179560960
    at Object.write (fs.js:676:5)
    at writeAll (fs.js:1458:6)
    at fs.js:1508:7
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:180:23) {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}
mbploreto:podping loretoparisi$ node gunzip.js 
(node:23322) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Invalid string length
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
    at Extract.<anonymous> (/gunzip.js:44:43)
    at Extract.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at Extract.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at finishMaybe (/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:624:14)
    at /node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:599:5
    at Extract._final (/node_modules/tar-stream/extract.js:254:3)
    at callFinal (/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:590:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:23322) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https:/nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23322) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The error seems to be related to the line

```
if (chunks.length) {
```

[UPDATE]
I have found a possibile workaround to avoid the `ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE`, but the file type saved seems to be wrong, using `Duplex`:

```
extract.on('finish', async function () {
        if (chunks && chunks.length) {
            const myReadableStream = bufferToStream(Buffer.from(chunks));
            myReadableStream
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destPath))
                .on('close', async function () {
                    logger.info("wrote %s", destPath);
                })
                .on('error', (error) => {
                    logger.warn("error:%@", error.toString());
                })
        }
})
```

where `bufferToStream` is

```
function bufferToStream(myBuuffer) {
        let tmp = new Duplex();
        tmp.push(myBuffer);
        tmp.push(null);
        return tmp;
    }
```

This will avoid the `RangeError`, but the extracted file is of type `data`, not in the original format (in my case was a sqlite database file):

```
file my_extracted_archive.db  data
```

The only working solution so far was not using node to unarchive but `tar` with child process:

```
  async function tarspawn() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var tar = spawn('tar', ['-xzvf', tmpPath, '-C', './']);
        tar.on('exit', function (code) {
            if (code === 0) {
                return resolve(tmpPath);
            } else {
                var error = new Error();
                error.code=code;
                return reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here are all the approaches [used](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/8339cdf44cca0223d976de5cd213d122).

Comment: Would you mind sharing a complete error output? It's hard to guess where the error could be. Maybe your chunks array got too big, but we need error output to prove that :)

Comment: @Max I have added the whole stacktrace!

Comment: So RangeError comes from fs, I can see some writeAll and Object.write names in the call stack. I bet chunks array indeed got really big. You can log chunks array length while pushing the data in that array. If it's true and it does exceed the range, you may want to chunk the data differently and/or batch fs writes.

Comment: Uhm this seems to be related to https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20498

Comment: It seems to be fixed, we have the same error, but apparently a different cause... You can 
try my suggestion about logging chunks array size and/or batch writes to a file - so far, these are the only reasonable points to try

Comment: @Max have a look, using `Duplex` stream seems a good workaround, but output file format seems to be wrong.