# using Node.js FormData to post Buffer as file not sending Buffer contents

Tags: node.js, axios, form-data

I have a image saved in a buffer I would like to upload to a webserver without need to saved it to disk. I am using Axios as the lib for handling the post request

My code for posting is as follows

```
const payload = new FormData();
payload.append('file', buffer, { filename: 'unknown.png', contentType: 'image/png', knownLength: buffer.toString().length });
const token = await RetreiveToken();
const resp = await Axios.post(`https://api.novastudios.tk/${endpoint}`, payload, {
  headers: {
    ...payload.getHeaders(),
    'Authorization': token
  },
  maxBodyLength: 20971520,
  maxContentLength: 20971520,
});
```

The response from the server is a 500, upon having the web server log the incoming file I found that no file data was being sent (But the server was receiving a proper length header). I have tried converting the buffer to a [Readable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44091532/816620), and a [Duplex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62678816/10809344) but again nothing. I also added the filename, contentType and length parts but nothing either. Using electron + node.js for client and asp.net api for server)

Comment: Did you try to add a test route to receive such file and send a test request to it to verify either a file content is received or not?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes I have, it works with a normal file but the moment I change it to using a Buffer it doesn't work. Ive also confirmed it works using the API's testing page aswell

Comment: So it works sending a buffer to a test route? Did I get you right?

Comment: @Anatoly No, it doesn't, the route gets the request but it doesn't receive the buffer content. Sorry for making that kind of confusing

Comment: Did you add the multer middleware on receiving route locally?

Comment: No, but Node.js is only for the client side, the server is a ASP.net API

Comment: To test if you send a file correctly, please add and setup multer for your local node,js and a test receiving route.