# Reproducing fs.createReadStream with a buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, stream, buffer

I need to send a pdf to an api with formData.
I download the pdf which when logged look like this: `<Buffer  6d 61 67 65 49 2f ... >`
If I `fs.writeFileSync` it is perfectly readable.
But I want to try to pass it to the api without having to write it with `fs`, to manipulate the pdf as a buffer.
My post look like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('access_key', this.config.redacted);
formData.append('redacted','redacted');
formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream('./filename.pdf'));
return post('urlRedacted', formData, {
    headers: formData.getHeaders(),
})
```

This request will succeed and but it requires me to write the file with `fs`, which I want to avoid.
I tried a few things like using the library `node-streamifier` to help me create readable stream from a buffer, but the api send me back an error: `{ error: 'Invalid parameter \'file\' or \'bucket\': Object expected' }`.

So my question is, how to reproduce `fs.createReadStream` behaviour, which seems to be the only one working for my use case?

note: I tried to implement  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18190310/6480755) like this: `formData.append('file', createReadStream(myBuffer))` and like this `formData.append('file', createReadStream(myBuffer,{ encoding: 'binary' }))` but did not changed anything to the error.

SOLUTION:

fs was streaming the data and was intelligently adding some info from the file that it was reading and thus provided this line at the start of the stream of data:

```
_streams:
[ '----------------------------622545709057705753853273\r\nContent-
Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="tickets.pdf"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n',
```

This data were required to be a valid upload, so I added them to the my formData like this: 
`formData.append("file", buffer, {contentType: "application/pdf", filename: "tickets.pdf"})`

It seems to have something to do with `Blob`, which I know nothing about! But this solution work perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recreated the FormData object as JSON and ended up using the following.

```
const formData = {
  file: {
    value: (my-file.pdf as a Buffer),
    options: {
      contentType: 'application/pdf',
      filename: 'my-file.pdf'
    }
  }
```