# Convert buffer to readStream

Tags: node.js, stream

I have endpoint which is receiving files and need to send these files to 3rd party. However i'm not converting these files properly cuz i receive `Invalid request format` but if i read the file from fs the file is successfully deployed. How to create readStream from the input file? I tried `Readable.from(file.buffer)` still error. If i pass `createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), 'images...'))` is working as expected, here is the script.

```
export const deployFile = async (
  file: Express.Multer.File,
  httpService: HttpService,
): Promise<string> => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  // Working
  // formData.append('file', createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), '/images/1.jpeg')));

  // Not working
  formData.append('file', Readable.from(file.buffer));

  try {
    const observable = httpService
      .post(process.env.PINATA_BASE_URL + '/pinning/pinFileToIPFS', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`,
          pinata_api_key: process.env.PINATA_API_KEY,
          pinata_secret_api_key: process.env.PINATA_API_SECRET_KEY,
        },
      })
      .pipe(map((response) => response.data));

    const response = await lastValueFrom(observable);

    return response.IpfsHash;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error deploying image reason: ${error.response.data.error}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a Buffer into a ReadableStream in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230487/converting-a-buffer-into-a-readablestream-in-node-js)

Comment: @Molda what is the img_string actually, this is the data that i'm receiving when image is uploaded:

{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '245509749_237479131761955_2631090030549449386_n.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e2 02 1c 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 02 0c 6c 63 6d 73 02 10 00 00 6d 6e 74 72 52 47 42 20 58 59 5a 20 07 dc 00 01 00 19 ... 61097 more bytes>,
  size: 61147
}

Comment: I have it here as part of the not working example: 

formData.append('file', Readable.from(file.buffer));

but still looks like different output than the createReadStream()

Comment: Try to turn the buffer into string before passing it to Readable. `formData.append('file', Readable.from(file.buffer.toString()));` That's what the 1st answer recommends.

Comment: @Molda thanks but even with ` formData.append('file', Readable.from(file.buffer.toString()));` still getting the error: Invalid request format :(